# If value is "AA" , store all the values of column G in one variable that contains letters "AA"

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, multiple-columns

I've been asked to create a script that will loop through one year of stock data for each run and return the total volume each stock had over that year.

I also need to display the ticker symbol to coincide with the total stock volume.

My result should look as follows (note: all solution images are for 2015 data).

https://tec.bootcampcontent.com/Tecnologico-de-Monterrey-Coding-Boot-Camp/TECMC201905DATA2/raw/master/Week%202%20-%20VBA%20Scripting/Homework/Instructions/Images/easy_solution.png

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim counter As Long
Dim x As Double





For i = 1 To 1000
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "A" Then
        Range("I2").Value = "A"
        counter = counter + Cells(i, 7).Value
        Range("J2").Value = counter

    ElseIf Cells(i, 1).Value = "AA" Then
        Range("I3").Value = "AA"
        counter = counter + Cells(i, 7).Value
        Range("J3").Value = counter
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

I expect to get all the sums in "x" cell in total volume for each ticker, I accomplished the first one, but as the count gets the last value the second one gets another result

Comment: why not use `COUNTIF` formula?

Comment: Its easy to accomplish what I want with that formula. But I need to do it in vba (macros)

Comment: ```application.worksheetfunction.COUNTIF(.Range("A1:A1000"), "=" & "A")```. There is a VBA function for every excel formula, will be much faster than looping.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done a number of ways but i just modifying your code a little for correct working.

1. Since You are counting two parameters, you should use two counters. One for "A" another for "AA".
2. No need to Keep lines writing results (like `Range("I2").Value = "A"`  `Range("J2").Value = Counter`etc) within loop. Finally write values to the desired cell after completion of loop

Final code would be

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim Counter As Long, Counter2 As Long
Dim x As Double


For i = 1 To 1000
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "A" Then
        Counter = Counter + Cells(i, 7).Value
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1).Value = "AA" Then
        Counter2 = Counter2 + Cells(i, 7).Value
    End If
Next i

Range("I2").Value = "A"
Range("J2").Value = Counter
Range("I3").Value = "AA"
Range("J3").Value = Counter2
End Sub
```

The Simplest VBA solution may be

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Range("I2").Value = "A"
Range("J2").Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A1:A1000"), "A", Range("G1:G1000"))
Range("I3").Value = "AA"
Range("J3").Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A1:A1000"), "AA", Range("G1:G1000"))
End Sub
```